# Lasso Trim fails to create solid in Sculpt Mode

Tags: modeling, objects, sculpting

Blender 3.4.1, Win 10 64. I watched several tutorials but mine doesn't behave like the videos. I finally got to draw odd shapes but they do not fill-in. No object, no depth, no color. Drawing figure disappears when releasing LMB.     [image: screen shot]